# Is there a way to share the guest OS Internet connection with the host OS with in VMware?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I have an USB Wi-Fi board without drivers for Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion). Sometimes I have to connect to the Internet using the external board and need to pass the Ubuntu Internet connection running on VMware Fusion to my Mac. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can ssh from your Mac to your ubuntu server:

```
ssh -D 1080 -f -C -q -N <ubuntu-user>@<ubuntu-ip>
```

The IP address should be on a host only network between your Mac host and Guest OS. If you don't have it already, you will need to create / assign one.

And then, change your browser to use your 127.0.0.1:1080 as socks proxy. However, it only works for the browser or application that supports socks proxy.

To make it work transparently, you will need to setup NAT on the Ubuntu. Here is one example:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/307603/configure-nat-in-ubuntu-12-04

You will also need to change your Mac's route to point to ubuntu, again through the use of the private addresses on a host only network.

Answer (score 0):

you can also change the default route of the host OS to the IP address of the guest OS.
also remember to add a static route from the guest OS to the host if they can't ping each other.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you need to used a "Bridged" connection in your virtual network adapter using auto-detect.

Fusion has three virtual networks: Bridged (which usually be auto-detect of your physical network connection), Host-Only (which gives access between the host and the guest only), and NAT (which will be a different subnet than your host machine and will give access to the host and the internet connection).

The issue maybe that your Bridged connection is not set to auto-detect (most likely it is bound to your physical network adapter)

Your Ubuntu machine should then use the NAT to get access to both your Mac and the Internet.

ie. your Mac might be on Network 192.168.1.x/24  and your Ubuntu machine would be on Network 192.168.2.x/24 and the virtual machine configured to use the NAT.

Comment: Can you offer more detail?

Comment: Yes please, can you post step by step on how to configure the VM and Mac OS?